# Specification of Observables in TypeScript with Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a service that returns an Observable that my components can subscribe to. But I get the following error:

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable'.
```

I am currently running build alpha.44, and below you will find some code that reproduces the problem.

```js
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'angular2/core';

export class Backend {
    http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.getTeams().subscribe();
    }

    public getTeams(): Observable {
        return this.http.get('/api/teams')
            .map(JSON.parse);
    }
}
```

Changing the code to return "any" type seems to work, but that removes some of the advantages of using TypeScript. Is there any good way to be able to use strict types for Observables in current builds of Angular2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's returning from `http.get` is [`Observable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/5.0.0-alpha.6/src/Observable.ts) from [`rxjs`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS), not angular2 [`Observable`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/facade/async.ts#L45). As temporarily solution you can import `rxjs Observable` from "@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Observable" (see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gqAZZ6tcebOhskUG07JR?p=preview)).

```js
import Observable from '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Observable';

class Backend {
  // ...
  getTeams() : Observable {
    return this.http.get('api/teams.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

But IMHO changing the code to return "any" is the best solution at this moment. They do it [in angular2 http module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts#L116) for now.

Comment: I will accept the answer. And id like to add that I also think that just going with "any" for now might be the best solution and just fix it as soon as the Observable-adapter in angular2 gets the proper interface.

Comment: Note for people finding this question in the future: from build 46 the http.get not returns an Observable<Response>, which extends RxObserbable.

Answer (score 0):

use this to ditch ngc errors over this sort of methods which returns observable

```
yourMethod(...arguments): Observable<any> {}
```